# Mapnik 2.2 disappearing markers (MarkerSymbolizer)

Tags: mapnik

I'm using Mapnik v2.2.0 from Python 2.7 in an Ubuntu 16.04 environment.  The application generates maps with a set of MarkerSymbolizers at various coordinates.  In one map, when the MarkerSymbolizers are set to 25x25 pixels, one of the markers does not appear.  If the marker size is set to 15x15, all of the markers appear.

The markers are loaded from a csv file:

```
    layer = mapnik.Layer('GPS_tracking_points')
    layer.datasource = mapnik.CSV(file=leak_file_name, layer_by_index=0)
```

The styling is below:

```
            point_style = mapnik.Style()
            point_rule = mapnik.Rule()
            point_filter = mapnik.Filter ("[val] > 10")
            point_rule.filter = point_filter
            point_point_symbolizer = mapnik.MarkersSymbolizer()
            point_point_symbolizer.width = mapnik.Expression ('25')
            point_point_symbolizer.height = mapnik.Expression ('25')
            point_point_symbolizer.fill = mapnik.Color ('#ff0000')
            point_point_symbolizer.allow_overlap = True
            point_point_symbolizer.opacity = 0.5 # semi-transparent
            point_rule.symbols.append(point_point_symbolizer)
            point_style.rules.append(point_rule)
            map_canvas.append_style('high', point_style)
```

Screenshots are below.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Image missing Marker]

[image: Image with all markers]

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be related to the way Mapnik 2.2 handles styling in code vs xml.  I moved the styling specification to an xml file and everything works as expected.

The answer was found here:  https://github.com/mapnik/python-mapnik/issues/117